# unpublish node when edit it

Tags: nodes

I have a content type calles survey, When admin deletes a survey, the survey results should still be accessible and not deleted as well. So I want to unpublish the node when click on the delete button(it will be better to change this delete button to unpublish button). but I dont know how to unpublished a node.
Any solution / alternative / suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, In my case i did it by updating the node and node_revision table's status column set to "0".following code is for form submit action you can do it for your delete action..

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'your form')   {
 $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';
 }

}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
if (//your condition)
            {
            $query = db_update('node')
            ->fields(array(
            'status' => 0,//unpublished the node
                ))
            ->condition('nid',$form['nid']['#value'], '=')
            ->execute();

            $query = db_update('node_revision')
            ->fields(array(
            'status' => 0,//unpublished the node
                ))
            ->condition('nid',$form['nid']['#value'], '=')
            ->execute();
            }
        //  drupal_flush_all_caches(); 

}
```

Comment: hi madhurjya,thanks for your answer,i've tried your code in my site,it can update the status,but what I want is to hidden the delete button,it seems no work on this. so I tried other ways. and Thanks again.

Comment: ok...you can unset the delete button...any way finally you got your goal.even i got an another option from Jayendra Kainthola. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 1):

You can find below code snippets for unpublished node.

```
function custom_feature_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {

    $form['actions']['delete']['#submit'] = array('custom_feature_node_delete_submit');

  }

}

function custom_feature_node_delete_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_state['values']['status'] = 0;

  $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
  node_save($node);

  $form_state['redirect'] = node_access('view', $node) ? 'node/' . $node->nid : '<front>';

}
```

Kindly see that you need to change `article_node_form` with your node edit form id.
If you do not know, how to check form id, you can use `print $form_id` in `custom_feature_form_alter()` function.

Comment: hi Jayendra,thanks for your answer. I used the module 'publish button' for my special content type and it works for me. And still thank you.